# Cannot Delete Knowledge Articles

Tags: apex, data-loader

I am trying to delete knowledge articles via Workbench. I am receiving the following error:

```
InvalidJob: No delete access for object:Knowledge__kav
```

I am the system admin, so I definitely have access. Is there a Salesforce "Gotcha" that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete draft articles, draft translations of articles, or archived articles, but not published articles or translations.

Regarding your query: I assume you're trying to delete published articles, first remove them from publication by choosing edit or archive.

for more information please check the below resource link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_delete.htm&type=0

Comment: This does not solve the issue. From workbench I have no delete access. Yet I have delete access and am a knowledge user

Comment: Are you deleting published articles

Comment: No, these are all unpublished/archived

Comment: It will definitely work i have tried and it's working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going into the UI of Salesforce and going to the knowledge tab and bulk unpublishing articles. Once they were drafts/archives, I would delete in bulk by selecting many at once.